# how to get hindi font value from url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting hindi value in query string .

`?q=विषय` 
 I want to echo this value in my php code . 
I am getting this value in $_GET['q'],but it  echo value in other formate not as expected (विषय).Thanks in advance.

Comment: Character encoding issue. use UTF-8.

Comment: it not working .. it print <meta charset="utf-8" />%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%AF

Comment: Please post a more full picture of your code. From your comment above it appears you have zero HTML markup. Is this the case? I assume no, but you need to show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HTML5 use `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

For HTML 4.0.1 use

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`